# How to call a genre of art with perfectionistic figures?

Tags: images, color-theory, art

I really like a good combination of clear and harmonic colors and figures. For example, figures can be like in the pictures shown below:

[image]

[image]

... or in these other two links

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Usm, welcome to GD.SE! I have a very hard time understanding your question? Are you asking for the genre for the 2 images above? I don't see how these images would fit in the same genre. What does perfectionistic figures mean? Are you referring to geometric art?

Comment: hmm.. 'minimalism' comes to my mind. Second image however I'd describe merely as constructivism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second image resembles the genre of [geometric abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_abstraction).

Another example of geometric abstraction is the cover of the album [*Perfect Symmetry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_Symmetry_%28Keane_album%29) by the rock band Keane.

[image: Perfect Symmetry by the rock band Keane]